# How to implement an home screen icon behaving as button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am thinking for something and having no idea how feasible that idea is.

I want to create an icon on home screen and when user clicks on it the icon lights up(Showing the app is ON) otherwise it's not.

Can anyone with any idea weather it's feasible or not.
if... Yes! then how to implement this.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a [home screen app widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) that implements your desired UI and functionality.